# Create multiple csv's from a sorted datatable in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create multiple cvs's from a sorted datatable in C#.  I can created a master cvs from the table but I need to split the master table in to several csv's based on one of the columns.  I have tried making a list with each item and doing a foreach loop on the list and using the list item to add the row to the csv.  It works on the first item but not subsequent items.  This is what I have tried.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
foreach (string Sender in listSenders)
{
            
    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dtPHLIP251.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
        Select(column => column.ColumnName);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

    foreach (DataRow row in dtPHLIP251.Rows)
    {                   
        if (row[2].ToString() == Sender)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
            //row.Delete();
        }
        else
        {                       
            break;
        }
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\nkr7\\Desktop\\DMBErrors\\PHLIP251ErrorsProd" + strDate + Sender + ".csv", sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does this "not work"?  When you debug, what specifically fails?

Comment: `break` exits the `foreach` loop. Did you intend to do `continue` instead so that you just go to the next item in the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0):

The `File.WriteAllText` should be outside of the inner `foreach`, and there is no need for the `break`. The `StringBuilder` is most likely only needed in the outer `foreach` and can be created each loop.

```cs
foreach (string Sender in listSenders)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dtPHLIP251.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                  Select(column => column.ColumnName);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

    foreach (DataRow row in dtPHLIP251.Rows)
    {                   
        if (row[2].ToString() == Sender)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
            //row.Delete();
        }
    }
    
    File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\nkr7\\Desktop\\DMBErrors\\PHLIP251ErrorsProd" + strDate + Sender + ".csv", sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I made the changes but it adds all the records to each CSV after the first one.    I tried adding sb.Clear() but it still does it.

Comment: I figured it out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Donald - if the answer helps solve your question, then upvote & accept the answer :)